# How to read input in java with slash using scanner?

Tags: java

I want to ask about how to get the value from user input input in java with scanner.

eg
the input is : 1000/2

i want to get like this
a = 1000 and
b = 2.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Get it as a [single string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine) and [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) it by `/` and [convert it to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java) if needed.

Comment: any example sir ?

Comment: Check the links.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Reader reader = new StringReader("1000/2");
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter("/")) {
    int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
}
```

output

```
a = 1000, b = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
String s[] = scannerObject.next().split("/"); // split the input at once
int a = Integer.parseInt(s[0]); // convert string to integer
int b = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the splicing method.
a = [YOUR VAR].substring([YOUR SPLICING POS])